# WPF DataGrid problem with ObservableCollection and refreshing DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

after saving new items to database, DataGrid shows only this new items.

For example I have in my collection:

- 0000

Trying to add:

- 1111
- 2222

What I expected:

- 0000
- 1111
- 2222

What I get:

- 1111
- 2222

---

My VieModel inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged 
In my ViewModel I load the data:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            var listOfbranches = context
                .Branches_Table
                .ToList();

            Branches = new ObservableCollection<Branch>(listOfbranches);
        }
```

I have defined my ObservableCollection (maybe wrong definition):

```
private ObservableCollection<Branch> _Branches { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Branch> Branches
    {
        get { return _Branches; }
        set
        {
            _Branches = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Branches");
        }
    }
```

And button with action:

```
public void MyAction()
    {
        var listOfbranches = new List<Branch>
        {
            new Branch { BranchCode  = "1111", BranchID = "12121212"},
            new Branch {BranchCode  = "2222", BranchID = "21212121"}
        };

        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            context.Branches_Table.AddRange(listOfbranches );
            context.SaveChanges();
            Branches = new ObservableCollection<Branch>(listOfbranches);
        }
    }
```

In my View xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Branches,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1">
```

any comments will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I see the reason is because you are giving it a new instance here `Branches = new ObservableCollection<Branch>(listOfbranches);`. You basically need to add to the list and not create a new list!
What you should do is add to the list and may be invoke `OnPropertyChanged("Branches");` explicitly after the add.

Comment: as you can see you are assigning a new object to `Branches ` every time which is clearing old values you can use `Branches.AddRange(listOfbranches)`

Comment: Ok, I understand, but How to add listOfBranches to this observableCollection ? I dont see .AddRange method...

Comment: ok I just do foreach item in listOfBranches and then Branches.Add(item) thanks for help :)

Comment: listOfbranches.AddRange(Branches);